# How to save multiple serialize data in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, serialization

These are the two variable that holds data in array that I want to save in database and serialize before it will save. If I save one variable only ex $add_item_overview.. the serialize data of overview will save but the other one variable is not..and it gives me an undefined error in every parameter that I declare.

```
    $add_item_overview = array(
        "item_brand" => $_POST['brand'],
        "item_model" => $_POST['model'],
        "item_submodel" => $_POST['submodel'],
        "item_price" => $_POST['price'],
        "item_yearmodel" => $_POST['year'],
        );

    $add_item_specs = array(
        "engine_capacity" => $_POST['engine_capacity'],
        "engine_type" => $_POST['engine_type'],
        "engine_compression" => $_POST['engine_compression'],
        "engine_broke" => $_POST['engine_broke'],
        "performance_power" => $_POST['performance_power'],
        "performance_torque" => $_POST['performance_torque'],
        );
```

This is my serialize variable and ff sql statement.

```
$add_item_overview_serialize = serialize($add_item_overview);
$add_item_specs_serialize = serialize($add_item_specs);

$sql = "INSERT INTO item_newcar_temp(item_overview,item_specs) VALUES ('". $add_item_overview_serialize ."','" . $add_item_specs_serialize . "')";
```

Comment: if you do not sanitize your input from a php post, then you will *potentially* cram your db with 2nd level sql injection attacks (time bombs waiting til later)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are concatenate these two variables in SQL with comma which leads you to error.Because Mysql thinks that it is comma separated two columns.

You can use this code

```
$add_item_overview_serialize = serialize($add_item_overview);
$add_item_specs_serialize = serialize($add_item_specs);

$final_serialize = $add_item_overview_serialize.",".$add_item_specs_serialize;  //First concatenate them then use in SQL.

$sql = "INSERT INTO item_newcar_temp(item_specs) VALUES ('". $final_serialize . "')";
```